# Blender 2.8 - texture does not appear on extruded circle

Tags: texturing, extrude

In Blender 2.8, working from a new file, I have created a mesh circle and extruded it into a cylinder.  I then attempt to apply a texture using settings that work on cubes and cylinders.  But in the case of the extruded circle, the texture does not appear (in Render mode).

My question:  what do I need to do to get the texture to appear on the extruded circle?

[image]

Comment: Would be helpful if you cropped your screenshot before posting

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to UV Map the extruded cylinder. The reason why textures appear on a cylinder (and cube) created from the Add menu is because those are basic shapes that are used a lot, so they are already set up (which means UV mapped) for using textures, but since you extruded your cylinder from a circle, it doesn't have a UV map yet. I suggest looking up tutorials on the internet on how to learn to UV map models, because it is a very important thing to know.

UV mapping a cylinder is trivial, any basic tutorial will do.

Comment: Thanks - that was the insight I needed.  Would you have any suggestions as to my next question?  https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/149322/python-2-8-transform-resize-uv-map-instead-of-object